# Grouped cell in ag-grid is not setting new value on editing the cell even if setting enableGroupEdit as true

Tags: angular, ag-grid

For grouped/aggregated cell, I have set enableGroupEdit as true to make cell editable.
While editing the cell, it is returning event.oldvalue same as event.newvalue.
Can you please tell me how we can fetch the new and old values?